# How to prove that a solution set to $y'=Ay$ is an ellipse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question states:
[image]

After finding eigenvalues and simplifying I got the answer to (a) as:
$$y_1(t)=cos(2t)+sin(2t)$$
$$y_2(t)=-sin(2t)$$

But I am not sure how to prove that it is an ellipse. Tue The direction of the ellipse can be found as clockwise. period can easily found to be $\pi$. Also, how do you find the principal axes?

Comment: I'd say: notice that $y_2^2+(y_1+y_2)^2=1$

Comment: Thanks. But how does this prove that it's an ellipse?

Comment: I thought ellipse was the form $y_1^2 / a^2 + y_2^2 / b^2 = 1$

Comment: Not if you rotate it.

Comment: Thanks. And how do I find the principal axes?

Comment: Have you checked out a) carefully? See my answer below. The exercise might be wrong, as long as the resulting figure truly looks like an ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following G. Sassatelli’s comment, we observe that $y_2^2+(y_1+y_2)^2=1$. Expanding this gives us the quadratic $y_1^2+2y_1y_2+2y_2^2=1$, which represents some conic section. The discriminant of this equation is $2^2-4\cdot1\cdot2=-4\lt0$, so the equation represents an ellipse.

There are a few ways to find the principal axes of this ellipse. One is to find the eigenvectors of the matrix $Q$ of the quadratic form in the above equation: $$Q=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&2}.$$ A straightforward computation yields eigenvalues $\frac12(3\pm\sqrt5)$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(-1\pm\sqrt5,2)^T$. The major axis corresponds to the eigenvector of the *smaller* of the two eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is truly an ellipse.

If $a, b>0$ are given, a generic ellipse $\mathcal E_{a,b}=V\left( {\displaystyle \left({\frac {x}{a}}\right)^{2}+\left({\frac {y}{b}}\right)^{2}-1 } \right)$  * in canonical position (center at origin, and  whose major/minor axis is the $X$  axis and its minor/major axis is the  $Y$   axis ) with semi-axes of length $a$ and $b$ can be represented parametrically as
$$ {\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}x(t)&=a\,\cos t\\y(t)&=b\,\sin t\end{aligned}}}. $$

It is easily seen that an ellipse as above but with an arbitrary center $(X_c,Y_c)\in\mathbb{R}^2$  can be expressed as $$ {\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}x(t)&=X_c+a\,\cos t\\y(t)&=Y_c+b\,\sin t\end{aligned}}} .$$
Now, an ellipse $\widetilde{\mathcal{E}} $ in general position can be expressed as

$$ {\begin{aligned}\tilde{x}(t)&=X_{c}+a\,\cos t\,\cos \varphi -b\,\sin t\,\sin \varphi \\\tilde{y}(t)&=Y_{c}+a\,\cos t\,\sin \varphi +b\,\sin t\,\cos \varphi \end{aligned}}.$$

In each case, $t\in [0,  2\pi]$. Here $ \varphi$ is the angle of rotation  with respect to the $X$ axis taken counterclockwise (this can be done after a change of coordinates, namely, a translation of axes after  a rotation of axes). Explicitily, $\begin{pmatrix}\widetilde{x}(t)\\ \widetilde{y}(t)\end{pmatrix}=R_{\varphi} \begin{pmatrix} x (t)\\ y (t)\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}X_c\\Y_c\end{pmatrix}$, where $R_{\varphi}= \begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi &-\sin \varphi \\\sin \varphi &\cos \varphi \\\end{pmatrix}$ is a rotation matrix of $\varphi$ degrees.

In your case, one would have $X_c=Y_c=0, a\cos \varphi=1 , -b\sin \varphi=1, a\sin \varphi=0 $ and $b\cos \varphi=-1$. Since $a,b\neq 0$ and $\varphi$ is fixed, the above system doesn't have solutions. (Just note that $a\sin \varphi=0 $ would imply $\sin \varphi=0$, that is, $\varphi=k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb Z$)

Certainly it does look like an ellipse, but the above analysis shows that it is really not. It is simply some sort of *[oval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Oval.html)*. Namely, *a curve resembling a squashed circle but, unlike the ellipse, without a precise mathematical definition.*

[image]

*(More generally, for a polynomial $p(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}[x, y]$, we define $V\big(p(x,y)\big):=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: p(x,y)=0 \right\}$)

Comment: There’s a phase shift relative to this parameterization that you’ve overlooked: $t=0$ puts your parameterization at a vertex of the ellipse, but that’s not the case for the solution to the differential equation. If you include a term for this phase shift, you can find a rotation that works, but the calculation’s going to be messy.